# Play a random video on button click

Tags: javascript, html, video, random

I should start by saying I'm not good with JS and I'm still trying to learn it.

I have 10 mp4s and I need to play one at random on a button click. I'm having trouble making it happen and I've searched around for a solution but to no avail.

Here's what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div class="videoHolder">
    <video id="video" autoplay muted>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
<button type="button" name="button">Push to Play</button>
```

JS

```
var videos = [
    "mp4s/video1.mp4",
    "mp4s/video2.mp4",
    "mp4s/video3.mp4",
    "mp4s/video4.mp4",
    "mp4s/video5.mp4",
    "mp4s/video6.mp4",
    "mp4s/video7.mp4",
    "mp4s/video8.mp4",
    "mp4s/video9.mp4",
    "mp4s/video10.mp4",
];

var videoId = 0;
var elemVideo = document.getElementById('video');
var elemSource = document.createElement('source');
elemVideo.appendChild(elemSource);

elemVideo.addEventListener('ended', play_next, false);


function play_next() {
    if (videoId == 10) {
        elemVideo.stop();
    } else {
        video.pause();
        elemSource.setAttribute('src', videos[videoId]);
        videoId++;
        elemVideo.load();
        elemVideo.play();
    }
}
play_next();
</script>
```

This unfortunately doesn't do what I need. This code will play all 10 videos one after the other on page load, then stop. I need it to only play one of the random 10 videos when someone pushes the "Push to Play" button. And I need it to keep going after 10.

Like I said I'm not good with JS at all and I was able to find this code from browsing around and modifying it a bit.

Comment: give the button an id then use getElementById with that button id, then add a click event listener for that button element, and in that click handler function, put the `elemVideo.addEventListener...` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
<div class="videoHolder">
    <video id="video" autoplay muted src="">
    </video>
</div>
<button id='playRandom' type="button" name="button">Push to Play</button>
```

This is a really basic implementation of what you want

```
var videos = [
    "mp4s/video1.mp4",
    "mp4s/video2.mp4",
    "mp4s/video3.mp4",
    "mp4s/video4.mp4",
    "mp4s/video5.mp4",
    "mp4s/video6.mp4",
    "mp4s/video7.mp4",
    "mp4s/video8.mp4",
    "mp4s/video9.mp4",
    "mp4s/video10.mp4"
];

var videoId = getRandomInt(0, 9);
var elemVideo = document.getElementById('video');
elemVideo.setAttribute('src', '/' + videos[videoId]);
var btn = document.getElementById('playRandom');

btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var nextId = getRandomInt(0, 9);

    if (nextId != videoId) {
        playNext(nextId);
    } else {
        while (nextId == videoId) {
            nextId = getRandomInt(0, 9);
        }

        playNext(nextId);
    }
});

/* gets random whole number between 0 and 9 */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function playNext(id) {
    elemVideo.setAttribute('src', '/' + videos[id]);
    elemVideo.play();
}
```

This is a more robust implementation that includes a history of previously played videos so you don't play the same videos over again.

```
var videos = [
    "mp4s/video1.mp4",
    "mp4s/video2.mp4",
    "mp4s/video3.mp4",
    "mp4s/video4.mp4",
    "mp4s/video5.mp4",
    "mp4s/video6.mp4",
    "mp4s/video7.mp4",
    "mp4s/video8.mp4",
    "mp4s/video9.mp4",
    "mp4s/video10.mp4"
];
var playedVideos = [];

var videoId = getRandomInt(0, 9);
var elemVideo = document.getElementById('video');
elemVideo.setAttribute('src', '/' + videos[videoId]);
var btn = document.getElementById('playRandom');

btn.addEventListener('click', playRandom);

function playRandom(e) {
    var nextId = getRandomInt(0, 9);

    if (nextId != videoId) {
        if (!playNext(nextId)) {
            playRandom(e);
        }
    } else {
        while (nextId == videoId) {
            nextId = getRandomInt(0, 9);
        }

        if (!playNext(nextId)) {
            playRandom(e);
        }
    }
}

/* gets random whole number between 0 and 9 */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function playNext(id) {
    // checks if the video has already been played
    for (var src in playedVideos) {
        if (src == videos[id]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    elemVideo.setAttribute('src', '/' + videos[id]);
    elemVideo.play();

    // adds src to arr of played videos
    playedVideos.push(videos[id]);

    /*
     * Everything from here on is optional depending on whether you want to
     * - iterate over the arr of videos and play each videos at least once before starting over or
     * - you want to stop playing videos after playing each at least once
     */

    // empties the played videos arr and allows you to start playing a new set of random videos
    if (playedVideos.length() == 10) {
        playedVideos = []; 
        // if you'd like to stop playing videos altogether at this, point delete the previous statement and display a prompt saying the playlist is over
        // or if you'd like to reset the playlist, then remove the event listener ('playRandom') and display a reset button that starts everything over from the beginning.
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I implemented your code but unfortunately, it's still not working for me. The video area is blank and the Chrome inspector shows: <video id="video" autoplay muted src(unknown)></video>

Comment: Try it again. Just edited the code.
Also what errors are you getting in console?
If there are any errors then its probably because the video src couldn't be found. Code's solid. Try placing the 'mp4s' folder in the same folder as the html file.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm not getting any inspector errors, but the src shows unknown. See screenshot: [link](https://ibb.co/F0KrVXB). It's weird because that's what I was using earlier and it was finding the source.

Comment: Try the new edit. I forgot to initialize the 'src' attribute. Sorry was in a hurry. It should work now tho.

Comment: @jsDoian No worries. I appreciate the help. We're getting closer. Now the videos are playing but they're autoplaying on page load and going from one to the other. The button does nothing. I need them not to autoplay and to only play on button push. Also, I'm now getting a console error. See screenshot: [link](https://ibb.co/wC6Y7yL)

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry didn't read question to end (and was going off your code).

Comment: that did it. Thanks for everything!